# Pivot Table with Groupby - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by, multi-index

I'm trying to make a pivot table of data to look like the expected outcome below (second table) from the data in the first;

```
To Date         From    To    Quantity

10/11/2020   USA   Ireland  5
10/11/2020   USA   France   4
11/11/2020   USA   France   6
12/11/2020   USA   Jamaica  6
12/11/2020   USA   France   5
.
.
.
14/02/2021   USA   Ireland  65
```

```
           01/11/2020   01/12/2020   01/01/2021  01/02/2021

Ireland    15                                    65
France     10
Jamaica    6
```

I can groupby() it to get the monthly figures..
I would like the pivot table to have the total amount for each country..

```
df.index = qathist['To Date']
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df_m= df.groupby(by=[df.index.year, df.index.month]).sum()
```

..but then I'm removing other data etc and can't seem to pivot it correctly!

Any help much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the monthly, it's better with `to_period`. An you can through `To` to groupby, then unstack:

```
df.groupby(['To',df.index.to_period('M')])['Quantity'].sum().unstack()
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use pd.crosstab:

```
pd.crosstab(df['To'], df['To Date'], df['Quantity'], aggfunc='sum')
```

Comment: This is definitely useful! Would there be a way of summing the Quantity by month? So that the columns were monthly values instead of daily values?

Comment: Oh.. monthly, nah you need to groupby month first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a part of your original code and mix it with the `pd.pivot_table` function.

For example, if your original dataframe is `df` :

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df["To Date"])
pivot = df.pivot_table(values="Quantity", 
                       columns="To", 
                       index=[df.index.month, df.index.year],
                       aggfunc='sum')
```

The output is as follows

```
To               France  Ireland  Jamaica
To Date To Date                          
2       2021        NaN     65.0      NaN
10      2020        4.0      5.0      NaN
11      2020        6.0      NaN      NaN
12      2020        5.0      NaN      6.0
```

Hope it's useful!